# django-stdimage not saving the image

Tags: django

I'm using django-stdimage and using a ModelForm. When submitting the form it saves without a problem. The image urls are stored but no image files are stored in the uploaded folder or any other folder. Why could this be?

```
import datetime
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm
from ext.stdimage.fields import StdImageField

from south.modelsinspector import add_introspection_rules
add_introspection_rules([], ["^ext\.stdimage\.fields\.StdImageField"])

class Post(models.Model):
    image = StdImageField(upload_to='uploaded', thumbnail_size=(250, 250))
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=20000, blank=True)

class PostForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        exclude = ('date')
```

Answer (score 0):

The first your form has a error:

```
class PostForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        exclude = ('date') # change this line to this one: exclude = ('date',)
```

But I thing that the problem is that you don't have install PIL.

http://code.google.com/p/django-stdimage/source/browse/trunk/stdimage/fields.py#81